# Yii2 how to use built in mysql function in active record

Tags: activerecord, yii2

How to use built in MySQL function in Yii2 active record?
This is my query that I want to covert in active record.

And how to implement the same in `SearchModel`?

```
SELECT * FROM `dts_track` where concat(date_received,time_received) != concat(date_released,time_released)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a  string format for where

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = YourModel::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andWhere('concat(date_received,time_received) != concat(date_released,time_released)');

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: I did not know that I could use a string format. The correct syntax is `$query->andWhere('concat(dts_track.date_received,dts_track.time_received) != concat(dts_track.date_released,dts_track.time_released)');` Thanks you helped me.

Answer (score -2):

Let me contribute to a better life, in Search function use:

```
        if(isset($params['date_received']) AND isset($params['time_received'])){
            $datereceived = $params['date_received'].$params['time_received'];
        }

        if(isset($params['date_released']) AND isset($params['time_released'])){
            $datereleased = $params['date_released'].$params['time_released'];
        }

        $query->andWhere(':date1 != :date2', [':date1' => $datereceived , ':date2' => $datereleased ]);
```

Comment: It does not make any sense. It will compare two static values and result will be the same for all records. So it will not filter anything - it will either show all records or none.

Comment: Just the params date received and date released needed exists in model definitions. Debug $params ?